# What is the meaning of 'run with' in "I wouldn't run with that nickname."?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

I am watching the "Emily in Paris" Season 3, Episode 7.

What is the meaning of 'run with' in "I wouldn't run with that nickname."?

The following is an excerpt.

```
Gabriel: Bonjour, neighbors. 
Emily: Bonjour. 
Mindy: Hi. Fetching your own breakfast? Where's your boulangerie bish? 
Emily: She's referring to Camille. 
Mindy: I wouldn't run with that nickname. 
Gabriel: She's in Greece with Sofia. 
Mindy: Excusez-moi? 
Emily: What?
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've never encountered this usage in exactly this context, but it looks like someone else's way of saying *[I wouldn't] **go along with** [that]* - i.e. speaker is telling addressee that referring to Camille by the made-up nickname "boulangerie bish" isn't a good idea.

Comment: Normally, colloquial ***run with** [some approach to solving a problem or "working assumption"]* in such contexts means the subject will accept *[that method]* as a ***trial, test*** (to see if it works out). But in this case, it seems to be closer in meaning to *I don't **recommend** using that nickname.* But I've got no idea what a "boulangerie bish" is supposed to mean anyway - good luck figuring out everything these characters are saying to each other!

Comment: oh - I see "bish" is apparently now slang for "bitch" as a moron's way of referring to a woman. I wouldn't recommend trying to learn English from such a trashy source.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: It may be that's the *intended* meaning in this context, but can you find *any* dictionary (even Urban Dictionary, the lowest of the low) supporting that definition? So far as I'm concerned, *Let's run with that* always and only means *Let's give that a try and see how it works out*. I'm doubtful that any significant number of speakers would use ***run with*** to mean ***recommend***.

Comment: chatgpt says *In French, the word "biche" literally translates to "doe," the female deer. It is generally not used as a derogatory term akin to the way "bitch" is used in English*. Imho, the source text here is rubbish

Comment: Possibly one wouldn't run with that nickname for the same reason that one is ill advised to run with scissors? Because it would be dangerous in some way, e.g socially?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - _une (or un) biche_ can be slang for a beloved or well-liked spouse, lover, or close friend.

Comment: Thank you  FumbleFingers, Michael Harvey for many comments.  I found one seeming definition as James K pointed out below, but I thought the meaning does not seem quite right. So I posted the question here for better answer.  I just want to know the nuances of 'run with' instead using 'try', 'recommend' or 'use'.  The Emily in Paris is not of high quality drama, but I can learn some contemporary English of young people as a non-native speaker.  So it is useful to me anyway.  Thank you,

Comment: FumbleFingers, Michael Harvey, I watched Netflix drama Virgin River and The Good Witch, and they are quite good in learning English.  Do you have any good drama to recommend for non-native speaker learning more English?  I use Netflix only. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This idiom is actually found in the dictionary:

[run with something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-with)  Accept something, use it and/or develop it.

So "run with that nickname" means to accept and use a nickname.  The conversation here seems to centre around the use of ["Bishe" (literally "doe") a term of endearment for a girlfriend (similar to chérie)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29900/ma-biche-is-it-only-used-when-talking-directly-to-my-wife) but now old fashioned. She says not to "run with it" because of its phonetic similarity to English "Bitch" (an insult).

Don't use that French expression, as it will be misunderstood in America.

Comment: Those of us of a certain age may recall the Chabrol film, _Les biches_

Comment: Thank you James K for the comment.  I saw the definition you mentioned, but I thought it is not the right meaning because of ", use it and/or develop it." at first glance at the end. So I thought there might be a better meaning for the it.  Your additional explanation of bish really helps me understand the context better.  Why did the scritpt writer not use the common word like 'recommend' 'or 'use'  instead of 'run wiith'?  What is the  connotation there? Thank you.

Comment: It's not a formal conversation, and such expressions are common in informal chat. No special connotation, except that these people are chatting casually not talking like robots.

Comment: Thank you James K for the additional comment